# Adding 3 User Input Numbers together

Tags: java, sum, user-input

I am doing an exercise from a site where I am trying to add 3 numbers the user inputs only using three variables. The code they let you start off with is:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
int sum = 0;
int read;

// WRITE YOUR PROGRAM HERE
// USE ONLY THE VARIABLES sum, reader AND read!

System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
```

I was thinking of using a for loop but I keep getting stuck because I can only use three variables. reader is already being used by Scanner. sum is going to be changing values, and read is going to be a temporary value.

I would have used

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
```

But that would have only held 1 number. Any help I've been stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should satisfy the requirement:

```
for(read = 3; read > 0; read--) {
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    sum += Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: Or just `sum = reader.nextInt() + reader.nextInt() + reader.nextInt()`

Comment: Thanks jheim do you mind telling me how you came up with the solution.

Comment: Grab my latest edit. I was missing a semicolon, and changed `read >= 0` to `read > 0`.

Comment: Well, I tried to incorporate a use of all the variables you had listed. So I decided I would use `read` as my counter in the for loop. Since we needed to add three values, I set `read` to 3. The rest of the logic you had already, just incorporated the `+=` operator to add the values to `sum`. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it? It obviously doesn't scale to hundreds of numbers:

```
int read;
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
sum += read;

System.out.println("Enter a second number: ");
read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
sum += read;

System.out.println("Enter a third number: ");
read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
sum += read;
```

---

> No this is what i had as well, but it didn't work

Full version - this works for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;
    int read;

    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum += read;

    System.out.println("Enter a second number: ");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum += read;

    System.out.println("Enter a third number: ");
    read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    sum += read;

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 
22
Enter a second number: 
10
Enter a third number: 
50
Sum: 82
```

---

Of course, a simpler version based on what jheimbouch did would be better:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HelloWorld 
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sum = 0;

    for(int read = 1; read <= 3; read++) 
      {
      System.out.println("Enter number " + read + ": ");
      sum += Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
      }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

    }
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't compile? Doesn't add the numbers?

Comment: Hmm this is weird I had the same thing as your original one but it would always say read already has a value

Comment: Did you maybe have `int read = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());` which would mean you had defined `read`?